# How do I get closed questions out of my RSS feed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, rss

I'd rather not have to deal with closed questions.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a way, the point being that closed questions are *not* dead, they may even be extremely useful & interesting questions that just don't fit the topic or format of the site.

One thing you could try would be to build your own feed by using our [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/).